# java.lang.NullPointerException context.getSharedPreferences

Tags: android

i call `Notification n = new Notification(getContext());` in fragment,

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visibility) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visibility);

    if (visibility) {

        Notification n = new Notification(getContext());

        if (n.getNewNotificationsCount() > 0) {
            n.setNotificationsAsSeen();
            n.setNewNotificationsCount(0);
        }
    }

}
```

and get `nullpointerexception`

Here is Notification.class loader

```
public Notification(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences(NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS_PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);//here is error (NullPointerException)
    editor = pref.edit();
}
```

Comment: Obviously you have to get fragment's lifcycle into account ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must take into account, that the fragment gets activity Context only after it is attached to activity. It is safe to call this method in the `onCreate()` fragment's lifecycle method or later and not after `onDetached` was called.
Then you must take into account, that Fragment's `getContext()` method was added on API 23, so if you run the app build with SDK tools 23 on the device with lower API, you might get NullPointerException.